# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue Errror

Tags: c++

Getting  *Expression must be a modifiable lvalue error*, I've looked at other posts still doesn't make sense :/ Trying to make simple temperature converter.

1>C:\Users\whatsupnigeh\Desktop\Stuff\asmgodtm\Temperature_Converter\Temperature_Converter\Main.cpp(30,30): error C2106:  '=': left operand must be l-value

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
float final_temp;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitleA("Temperature Converter");

    cout << "{1} Fahrenheit -> Celsius" << endl;
    cout << "{2} Celsius -> Fahrenheit" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Selection: " << endl;
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter F*: " << endl << endl;
        float f;
        cin >> f;
        f - 32 * 5 / 9 = final_temp;
        cout << final_temp;

    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter C*: " << endl << endl;
        float c;
        cin >> c;
        c * 9 / 5 + 32 = final_temp;
        cout << final_temp;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    Sleep(3000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f - 32 * 5 / 9 = final_temp;` --> `final_temp = f - 32 * 5 / 9;`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states `Expression must be a modifiable lvalue` so the value on the left side of an assignment must be a variable.

As S.M. wrote above you'll have to turn your assignment the other way round.

`f - 32 * 5 / 9 = final_temp;` should be `final_temp = ((f - 32) * 5) / 9.;`

Comment: Wrong precedence. Should be `final_temp = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;`

Comment: @stark Thanks for the correction. I just copied the correction from the comment above!

Comment: You should always check that your answer is correct.  Many questions have multiple problems.